# Dialogflow Messenger CSS variables list

Tags: css, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm finishing chatbot in Dialogflow ES. I'm using Dialogflow Messenger integration. I managed to do embeding with appropriate HTML customizations and some CSS customizations. What I'm missing is the complete list of CSS variables.

In Google's help (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#css-customize) I can see 11 CSS variables listed, but googling further I found at least one more (--df-messenger-chip-border-color).

Does anyone know if the "official" variables list is the one to stick to or are there additional variables available? And if they are, is there a list somewhere?

I know I can do lots of things with jQuery or JS and update different chatbot elements' CSS on the fly after they are loaded by Google script but using specific variables is of course far more simple and far less time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer that I got directly from Google (asked the same question in Google groups):

The doc for messenger is missing some CSS variables. We will work on updating the doc. For now, one way to find all the supported CSS variables is to search "--df-messenger" in the script file (https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger/messenger-internal.min.js).